# How to use curl and an array of URLs together

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I found this code that does what I'm looking for on a single domain check. But I have a list of URLs that I would like to check. 
Can you and how would you create an array with curl?

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'HTTP code: ' . $httpcode;
```

Comment: You're lookig for the `cURL_mutli_*` functions documented here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php - I recommend you to try it by yourself. If you fail, just come back here ans ask. We're here to help :) But be careful: I don't know how many URL's you want to request somethin from. If they're too many, you can run into huge performance problems since the job will run in parallel.

Comment: You might also want to look into using a library like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), which provides a higher-level abstraction over the native `curl_*` functions, including sending multiple requests in parallel

Comment: Thank you both for your recommendations. They were a great help in better understanding what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want are `headers`, then instead of `curl` try:

```
$urls = array('http://www.example.com','http://www.example.com2','http://www.example.com3','http://www.example4.com');

$httpCodes = [];
foreach($urls as $url)
{
    $httpCodes[$url] = get_headers($url)[0];
}

var_dump($httpCodes);
```

This uses `get_headers()` to get the header data from a URL's response.

**Edit:** Or if you really want to use `curl`. you can use the following code with `curl_multi` instead:

```
$urls = array('http://www.example.com','http://www.example.com2','http://www.example.com3','http://www.example4.com');

$curlMultiReq = curl_multi_init();
$ch = [];
foreach($urls as $key => $url)
{
    $ch[$key] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_multi_add_handle($curlMultiReq, $ch[$key]);
}
$running = '';


do {
  curl_multi_exec($curlMultiReq, $running);
  curl_multi_select($curlMultiReq);
} while ($running > 0);


foreach(array_keys($ch) as $key){
  echo curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  echo "\n";  
  curl_multi_remove_handle($curlMultiReq, $ch[$key]);
}
curl_multi_close($curlMultiReq);
```